# Javascript: Can't handle events for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have put together a fun API for game creation. In the code I create a prototype for Mover and then extend it with several specific prototypes (Gold, Monster, and Hero). Each one is based on a img tag with a given ID. I use type-specific information in the constructor and a single template method for each type. Most of the functional code in Mover depends on those type-specific details. I have included one example for simplicity.

I use method calls in a separate script to create and destroy instances of the Mover child types. When I create and destroy one instance at a time everything works as intended. The image updates, the sound plays and it is removed after the correct delay. If I create two or more, however, only the last one works as expected. So if I make gold, moster, hero. Only the hero will remove correctly. The other two will play the audio, but don't appear to update.

I ran into the same problem when I tried to attach a function to the onclick event for more than one instance. Only the last one worked and the others did nothing. Obviously I'm missing something about the way java handles method assignments. Any explanation you can offer would help.
Thanks,
BSD

```
function Mover()
{
}

Mover.prototype.InitTag = function()
{
   this.HTMLtag.src=this.imageURL;
   this.HTMLtag.style.position="absolute";
   this.HTMLtag.style.width=characterSize;
   this.HTMLtag.style.height=characterSize;
   this.Position(Math.floor(Math.random()*(MaxW-characterSize)+(characterSize/2)),Math.floor(Math.random()*(MaxH-characterSize)+(characterSize/2)));
}

Mover.prototype.Destroy = function()
{
   var disp = this.HTMLtag.display;
   this.HTMLtag.src=this.destroyURL
   this.HTMLtag.display = disp;
   this.destroyAudio.play();

   this.RemoveTag();
}

function Monster(id)
{
   this.MonsterID = id;
   this.HTMLtag = document.getElementById("monster"+id);
   this.imageURL = "monster1.jpg";
   this.destroyURL = "monster2.jpg";
   this.destroyAudio = monsterAudio;
}

Monster.prototype = new Mover();

Monster.prototype.RemoveTag = function()
{
   var mID = this.MonsterID;
   setTimeout(function() {field.DeleteMonster(mID)}, 1000);
}

function Hero()
{
   this.HTMLtag = document.getElementById("hero");
   this.imageURL = "hero1.jpg";
   this.destroyURL = "hero2.jpg";
   this.destroyAudio = heroAudio;
}

Hero.prototype = new Mover();

Hero.prototype.RemoveTag = function()
{
   setTimeout(function() {field.DeleteHero()}, 5000);
}

function Gold(id)
{
   this.GoldID = id;
   this.HTMLtag = document.getElementById("gold"+id);
   this.imageURL = "gold1.jpg";
   this.destroyURL = "gold2.jpg";
   this.destroyAudio = goldAudio;
}

Gold.prototype = new Mover();

Gold.prototype.RemoveTag = function()
{
   var mID = this.GoldID;
   setTimeout(function() {field.DeleteGold(mID)}, 1000);
}
```

---------UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE-----------
I have at least partially fixed the problem. I have gotten it to work, but I still don't know why it didn't function as intended. I noticed that while my browser's (Chrome) developer tools could visually identify the most-recently-added Mover when it was being destroyed, it could not do so with the any other movers.

[Tag of most recently added Mover can be identified in Chrome developer tools.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ3OG.png)
This suggested that Mover.HTMLtag was not actually the same as document.getElementById('mover1'). I was able to confirm this by looking at the variables in the GoldField.DeleteMover. At the line indicated mover.src has not changed, but movers[id].HTMLtag.src has been correctly updated. In the most-recently-added case they were both the same.

```
GoldField.prototype.DeleteMover = function(id)
{
  var isHero = false;
  if(this.Hero!=null && id==this.Hero.myID)
  {
    this.Hero = null;
    isHero = true;

  }
  else if(this.Tower!=null && id==this.Tower.myID)
  {
    this.Tower = null;
  }

  var mover = document.getElementById("mover"+id);
  if(!isHero)
  {
    this.tag.removeChild(mover);//<<< HERE HERE HERE HERE
    delete this.movers[id];
  }
}
```

So, I changed one line in Mover.Destroy. By finding the tag by ID and setting the src. I was able to reliable behavior. It would appear that Mover.HTMLtag is not reliable the same after the second Mover is added. Any explanation?

```
Mover.prototype.Destroy = function()
{
   document.getElementById(this.HTMLtag.id).src=this.destroyURL;
   this.HTMLtag.src=this.destroyURL;//old method
   this.destroyAudio.play();

   this.RemoveTag();
}
```

On suspicion that this might extend to other updates to this.HTMLtag I set up some basic movement of the Hero. It works great, but if you add one additional Mover of any kind it no longer moves. That narrows down the question considerably. Why would constructing a second Mover cause the prototype members to change?

Comment: Have a look at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) Your way of doing Inheritance is probably the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Looking at that site, however, I'm not doing anything very different. Their preference for creating a variable to store the type constructor and then using Object.create to link the parent prototype does not seem to make any difference. In fact I revised the code to implement it in that way and the behavior is the same. Unless I am missing something specific in the reference. Please let me know.

Comment: Something else which may help. I can trace the execution of the Destroy method for each instance. the HTMLtag is properly set in each case and the src is updated. The audio plays. The tag is removed. I can hear the audio but the image is never updated. Only the most recently added on updates the image. Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide me a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with all the code.

Comment: How about a URL with a working sandbox and the code, etc. [link](http://allmybs.org/API/example.html).  I am more and more convinced that the issue is not event or inheritance. Everything works except the image update. I can see these objects disappear and I hear their destroy audio, but only the last one will update the src properly.

Comment: You never define `field` anywhere.

Comment: Very true. Obviously this is not the whole of the code. You can follow the link above to find everything, but this is sufficient to see the problem areas. For the purposes of this discussion the field object and its methods are called after the area of interest and could be empty methods for all that it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I debug your code and I found the cause of your problem. The problem was when you create a new instance of monster you storing a reference to it on the monster var. And when you delete it you don't delete / update the reference to it. So your delete function myField.DeleteMover(id) try to delete a monster already deleted. How to solve this.

```
// create an array to keep ref to our instances
var monsters= [];
// var monster = null;
function addMonster()
{
  // monster = goldField.AddMonster();⏎
  // push every monster in array
  monsters.push(goldField.AddMonster());
}

function killMonster()
{
  // if array.length is true
  if (monsters.length) {
    // call the destroy function on the last ref
    monsters[monsters.length - 1].Destroy();
    // remove the last ref from array using pop
    monsters.pop();
  }
//monster.Destroy();
}
```

This is working however I think all of this should be done in the objects itself. And you should not care about it here.

Another advice try to use more [array methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp). Avoid using delete on array index because it mess with index and count instead use splice(index, 1)  same for add item in array use push instead of arbitrary index.

Anyway funny game! Good luck to finish it.

Edit, after your answer I go back an test.
To make it work I do this.

```
// First go inGoldField.prototype.DeleteMover and replace the ugly delete index by
this.movers.splice(id, 1);
// Then in the Mover.prototype.Destroy
// This part is a a little blurred for me.
// the current HTMLtag looks good but when I console.log like this
console.log('before', this.HTMLtag);
this.HTMLtag = document.querySelector("#mover" + this.myID);
console.log('after', this.HTMLtag);
// They are not equal look like the first is outdated
```

You should convert all your delete and add to splice and push methods.
This is just a quick debug I don't know why the selector is outdated.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you like it. I'm writing this as an API for my students to work with this fall. Unfortunately, that was not the problem I was trying to resolve. the example code is just a bare-bones testing sandbox for the functionality in my API. Try these testing steps to see the issue. Add one monster. kill it. See it explode and hear it say "I will kill you". This is the right behavior. If you then add a monster and any other item, when you kill the monster you still hear it and it does disappear, but it no longer explodes. I don't know why the image isn't updating.

Comment: Mmmm. No. I copied your code into the method as indicated, but it is not having the desired effect. There is nothing wrong with using delete and add in any case. This merely uses the array object as a hash and it is the ground state of all objects in Javascript. In any case, the issue is not related to removing the tags, that happens just as intended. It is somehow related to changing the image src when it starts the destroy process.

Answer (score 0):

So I check the code again and I make it work without refreshing the selector. The problem is caused by the creation of dom element with innerHTML.

First reset

```
this.HTMLtag.src=this.destroyURL
```

Then instead of

```
//Mover.prototype.Destroy
this.tag.innerHTML+="<img id='mover"+this.moverCount+"'>";
```

I create a img dom el.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('id', 'mover' + this.moverCount);
this.tag.appendChild(img);
```

All Monsters are now deleted with the image.
I don't check for the hero but first you should update your innerHTML and reply if there is still a problem. I don't think there is any problem with some prototype.

Comment: BINGO! We have a winner. I'll read up on those methods and ensure that I'm showing the students the right methods. Thanks very much. That was the problem.