# How to replace a div content by "html content" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code a want to replace the innerHTML with html code how can i replace.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('forget_password_email')[0].innerHTML = "<div class='input-email form-group margin-bottom-30'>
<input type='email' id='lg_username' value='' class='input-email form-control' placeholder='Email *' />
</div>
<button  type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-theme btn-hv-dark btn-rounded btn-default btn-inline ' id='reset'>Reset</button>
";
```

Comment: yes dear please share

Comment: it will work directly.

Comment: Put all the code in a single line and add missing `)`.  Otherwise, what's the actual issue?

Comment: I agree with Put all the code in a single line (as javascript strings can not span multiple lines). But I don't see a missing `)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this with jquery. It is `.html()` function of jquery.

```
   $($(".forget_password_email")[0]).html("<div class='input-email form-group margin-bottom-30'><input type='email' id='lg_username' value='' class='input-email form-control' placeholder='Email *' /></div><button  type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-theme btn-hv-dark btn-rounded btn-default btn-inline ' id='reset'>Reset</button>");
```

Comment: This Answer Sloved My Problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you  missing class name ->"forget_password_email " is that a class name or id ? Because your code will work when you place  in your target html in like that:

```
<script>
        //Your javascript codes.
var text ="<div class='input-email form-group margin-bottom-30'>"+
"<input type='email' id='lg_username' value='' class='input-email form-control' placeholder='Email *' />"+
"</div>"+
"<button  type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-theme btn-hv-dark btn-rounded btn-default btn-inline ' id='reset'>Reset</button>"; 

document.getElementsByClassName('forget_password_email')[0].innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.innerHTML` is non-standard, and a terrible practice for many reasons. You should create a new element using the proper standard methods and and add it to the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Template literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Place your html content inside back tick(`). It will allow your text to be multi-line.

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('forget_password_email')[0].innerHTML = `<div class='input-email form-group margin-bottom-30'>
<input type='email' id='lg_username' value='' class='input-email form-control' placeholder='Email *' />
</div>
<button  type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-theme btn-hv-dark btn-rounded btn-default btn-inline ' id='reset'>Reset</button>`;
```

```html
<div class='forget_password_email'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this. Just setting innerHTML creates some bad side effects ([Javascript: Can't handle events for multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809948/javascript-cant-handle-events-for-multiple-instances)) I found that it made my web page unstable and prevented me from doing the sort of dynamic building I wanted.

What you should do is identify the tag you want. Then you can use that object to change any attributes OR append inner HTML nodes.

```
 var div = document.createElement("myDiv");
 div.setAttribute('someAttribute', value);
 var childTag = document.createElement('p');
```

Doing it this way does not introduce instabilities into the page. So for your code it would look something like this.

```
var tag = document.getElementsByClassName('forget_password_email')[0];
var childDiv = document.createElement('div');
childDiv.setAttribute('class', 'input-email form-group margin-bottom-30');
var childInput = document.createElement('input');
childInput.setAttribute('type', 'email');
childInput.setAttribute('id', 'lg_username');
....
tag.appendChild(childDiv);
tag.appendChild(childInput);
```